# python - Datetime calculation between two columns in python pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this: 
And this DataFrame is called`df_NoMissing_IDV`.

```
NoDemande   NoUsager  Sens  IdVehiculeUtilise  Fait  HeureArriveeSurSite   HeureEffective      Periods
42196000013  000001    +         287Véh          1  11/07/2015 08:02:07  11/07/2015 08:02:13    Matin
42196000013  000001    -         287Véh          1  11/07/2015 08:17:09  11/07/2015 08:17:13    Matin
42196000002  000314    +         263Véh          1  11/07/2015 09:37:43  11/07/2015 09:53:37    Matin
42196000016  002372    +         287Véh          1  11/07/2015 09:46:42  11/07/2015 10:01:39    Matin
42196000015  000466    +         287Véh          1  11/07/2015 09:46:42  11/07/2015 10:01:39    Matin
42196000002  000314    -         263Véh          1  11/07/2015 10:25:17  11/07/2015 10:38:11    Matin
42196000015  000466    -         287Véh          1  11/07/2015 10:48:51  11/07/2015 10:51:30    Matin
42196000016  002372    -         287Véh          1  11/07/2015 11:40:56  11/07/2015 11:41:01    Matin
42196000004  002641    +         263Véh          1  11/07/2015 13:39:29  11/07/2015 13:52:50    Soir
42196000004  002641    -         263Véh          1  11/07/2015 13:59:56  11/07/2015 14:07:41    Soir
```

I need to get the marge between column `HeureArriveeSurSite` and `HeureEffective`,and they are already `datetime.datetime()` data.

And here is a new `DataFrame` called `df1`.

```
df1 = df_NoMissing_IDV[(df_NoMissing_IDV['Sens'] == '+') & (df_NoMissing_IDV['Periods'] == 'Matin')]
```

And `df1` looks like this:

```
NoDemande   NoUsager  Sens  IdVehiculeUtilise  Fait  HeureArriveeSurSite   HeureEffective      Periods
42196000013  000001    +         287Véh          1  11/07/2015 08:02:07  11/07/2015 08:02:13    Matin
42196000002  000314    +         263Véh          1  11/07/2015 09:37:43  11/07/2015 09:53:37    Matin
42196000016  002372    +         287Véh          1  11/07/2015 09:46:42  11/07/2015 10:01:39    Matin
42196000015  000466    +         287Véh          1  11/07/2015 09:46:42  11/07/2015 10:01:39    Matin
```

Since they all are `datetime.datetime()` data, I tried to do the subtraction directly with:

```
df_NoMissing_IDV['DureeService'] = df1['HeureEffective']-df1['HeureArriveeSurSite']
```

But it returned `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'unicode'`

And I also tried to do the calculation with `datetime.time()` type, and it returned with `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'` What should I do with it?

**EDIT**

I convert columns in `df1` to `datetime()`:

```
df1.HeureArriveeSurSite = pd.to_datetime(df1.HeureArriveeSurSite)
df1.HeureEffective = pd.to_datetime(df1.HeureEffective)
```

But the next step is still wrong which returned: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

And if I convert columns in `df_NoMissing_IDV` to `datetime()`:

```
df_NoMissing_IDV.HeureArriveeSurSite = pd.to_datetime(df_NoMissing_IDV.HeureArriveeSurSite)
df_NoMissing_IDV.HeureEffective = pd.to_datetime(df_NoMissing_IDV.HeureEffective)
```

The same problem remains.

Any help will be appreciated~

Comment: I think you need convert columns to `datetime` - `df_NoMissing_IDV.HeureArriveeSurSite = pd.to_datetime(df_NoMissing_IDV.HeureArriveeSurSite)` 
`df_NoMissing_IDV.HeureEffective = pd.to_datetime(df_NoMissing_IDV.HeureEffective)`

Comment: you mean to convert columns in DataFrame =`df1` to `datetime`? Because columns in `df_NoMissing_IDV` were already in `datetime`. But the next step is still wrong. `df_NoMissing_IDV['DureeService'] = df1['HeureEffective']-df1['HeureArriveeSurSite']`, it returned: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`.

Comment: Hmmm. There are some duplicates. Can you add sample, which return error?

Comment: I try create some test data without sucess, but maybe it is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the cause of the error is that you have some dplicates in your data.

Try two things out:

```
df_NoMissing_IDV['DureeService'] = df1['HeureEffective'].values -df1['HeureArriveeSurSite'].values
```

Or:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

**EDIT:**
What you can also try is `timedelta`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> time_difference = df1['HeureEffective']-df1['HeureArriveeSurSite']
>>> time_difference_in_seconds = time_difference / timedelta(seconds=1)
```

Comment: The first one returned: `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`. And the second one returned : `ValueError: cannot insert level_0, already exists`

Comment: Try this: df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: It worked. And this column is added to the `DataFrame` `df1`,is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: you mean you have now the column "index"?

Comment: no, I have the column `DureeService` in the DataFrame `df1`. And I also have two more columns `index` and `level_0` in `df1`

Comment: In fact, your edited answer doesn't work. Yours first reply answered well.